# How to get nodes within the <content> tag in polymer 1.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I am trying to access the nodes in the content tag using `Polymer.dom(this).getDistributedNodes()` with no luck. I have also tried a variety of other methods including querying the shadowRoot directly.

I can't find anything in the documentation for 1.0 that explains how to do this. Does anyone know how to get nodes within `<content>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new version (1.2) of polymer was released a couple of days ago. Polymer blog explains new features regarding your issue, maybe you can find some help there.

https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2015/11/02/release-1.2.0/